# How to configure index.js with ApiProvider in RTK

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

ChatGPT suggests the following to configure the index.js at the root directory. I am not quite sure it is the most widely used practice. I want to ask your feedback.

```
    // index.js
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { ApiProvider } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
    import { api } from './api'; // Import your RTK Query API object
    import store from './store'; // Import your Redux store
    import App from './App'; // Import your main component
    
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <ApiProvider api={api}>
          <React.StrictMode>
            <App />
          </React.StrictMode>
        </ApiProvider>
      </Pro

vider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ApiProvider`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/ApiProvider) is supposed to be used when your React app ***is not*** already using Redux.

> ## Danger
>
> Using this together with an existing Redux store will cause them to
> conflict with each other. If you are already using Redux, please
> follow the instructions as shown in the [Getting Started guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/introduction/getting-started).

It's basically a light wrapper around a store instance that allows non-Redux-based React apps to use and leverage Redux-Toolkit Query for data wrangling.

Since you are using Redux already, as clearly indicated by the `react-redux` `Provider` component and `store`, your API slices should just be directly integrated in the `store`.

Basic example (see [Configuring the store](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview#configure-the-store)):

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
// Or from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query';
import { api } from './api';
... import state slice reducers ...

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ... all the other slice reducers ...

    // Add the generated reducer as a specific top-level slice
    [api.reducerPath]: pokemonApi.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(api.middleware),
});

// optional, but required for refetchOnFocus/refetchOnReconnect behaviors
// see `setupListeners` docs - takes an optional callback as the 2nd arg for customization
setupListeners(store.dispatch);
```

```
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```